# How to use an generated identity in an SQL statement (NetBeans JavaDB)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I have my table set up like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "CAMPAIGNS"
(  "campaignId" INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
   "campaignName" VARCHAR(200),     
   "campaignLocation" VARCHAR(200),
   "campaignManager" VARCHAR(200)

);
```

How should my INSERT statement look like, so I can make sure that the campaignId column gets automatically incremented, and I pick the rest of the values that will go in to the table?

Comment: Just for my understanding and for getting the tags clear, but isn't `IDENTITY` syntax from sql server, whereas in mysql this would be  `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply Make sure to make `campaignId INT Auto_Increment` then you don't need to put `campaignId` in your query like this :

```
String query = "INSERT INTO CAMPAIGNS (campaignName, campaignLocation, campaignManager) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

- You can learn more in [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO CAMPAIGNS (campaignName, CampaignLocation, CampaignManager)
VALUES ('Test','Sofia','Emil')
```

Comment: Yes!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this varies by the DB.  But leaving it out, or using a null should normally work.

```
insert into CAMPAIGNS(campaignId, campaignName, campaignLocation, campaignManager)
values (null, 'My Campaign', 'Australia','Bob');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
    connect.prepareStatement("INSERT into CAMPAIGNS (campaignName, campaignLocation,campaignManager) VALUES (?,?,?)");

preparedStatement.setString(1, "campaignName");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "campaignLocation");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "campaignManager");
```

Answer (score 1):

simply don't mention in insert

```
insert into CAMPAIGNS ( campaignName, campaignLocation, campaignManager) 
values ( 'campaignName_value', 'campaignLocation_value', 'campaignManager_value')
```

mysql do the rest

*PS don't unuseful double quotes*